# WebGL canvas size change doesn't update per viewport change

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I have the following code that I am using to resize my canvas and to keep the aspect ratio the same. It works fine but only at the initial WebGL load. I can see in the console that the canvas.width/height is being updated every time the window is resized using the `window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);` , but the actual GL canvas stays the same until the page is refreshed again.

```
function resizeCanvas(canvas) {
            const displayWidth  = window.innerWidth;
            const displayHeight = window.innerHeight;
         
            // Check if the canvas is not the same size.
            const needResize = gl.canvas.width  !== displayWidth ||
                             canvas.height !== displayHeight;
            
            canvasAspect = displayWidth / displayHeight;
            imageAspect = 3 / 4;
            imageMaxWidth = 900;
            imageMaxHeight = 1200;

            if (needResize) {
                if (displayWidth <= imageMaxWidth) {
                    canvas.width = displayWidth;
                    canvas.height = Math.round(displayHeight * canvasAspect / imageAspect);
                } if (displayWidth > imageMaxWidth) {
                    canvas.width = imageMaxWidth;
                    canvas.height = imageMaxHeight;
                } if (displayHeight <= imageMaxHeight) {
                    canvas.width = Math.round(displayWidth * imageAspect / canvasAspect);;
                    canvas.height = displayHeight;
                }
            }       
            
            gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            return needResize;
        }

        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
```

And this is where the images and function loads.

```
const loadImage = (d,i) => {
                gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(p,`t${i+1}`), i);
                
                const srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
                const img = new Image();
                img.onload = function(){
                        const [textureWidth, textureHeight] = [img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight];
                        gl.uniform2f(gl[`t${(i+1)}res`], textureWidth, textureHeight); 
                        gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
                        gl.activeTexture(i=== 0 ? gl.TEXTURE0 : gl.TEXTURE1);
                        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.createTexture());
                        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
                        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
                        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, srcType, this);
                        if(i === images.length - 1){
                            gl_update(gl);                  
                        }
                }
                img.src = d;
        }

        const tmp = start_gl("canvas1", getStringFromDOMElement('vs'), getStringFromDOMElement('fs'));
        const gl = tmp.gl;
        const p = tmp.program;

        const images = ["001.jpg","002.jpg"];

        images.map(loadImage);

        resizeCanvas(gl.canvas);
        gl_update(gl);
```

Comment: How do you use this function on the first load?

Comment: I updated the post with the remaining code.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the canvas height and width is to do with the resolution that the webgl context is presented in. What you are looking to do is change the size of the webgl viewport to reflect the size of innerWidth/innerHeight.

```
gl.viewport(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

will set the webgl viewport INSIDE the canvas to reflect the appropriate size so that you dont end up with half the viewing circle disappearing when you reduce the navigator resizes to half of what it was.

Comment: I think I need both of them to work? I've changed it to yours and it is scaling up the webgl viewport correctly but it gets cut off wherever the original canvas size was set to. The transform pivot point is also at the bottom left corner, how do I fix that?

Comment: gl.uniformMatrix4fv is used to set the projection matrix variable inside the vertex shader. The shader often contains something like gl_Position=projMtrx*viewMtrx*vPos When you change the viewport size, redo the equation for the fustrum in projMatrix which is something like
  this.projection=[c/aspect,0,0,0,0,c,0,0,0,0,(far+near)/(near-far),-1,0,0,(2*far*near)/(near-far),0];  (where c=1/Math.tan(lensRadians)